# How much knowledge of spread sheets i need to know for data warehousing

Tags: spreadsheet, data-warehouse

I am learning stuff so that i can enter data warehousing field.
I was reading the book on DW and it says knowledge of spreadsheets will be good for DW.

I have some time left before applying for jobs.
Should i start learning microsoft excel in advanced for DW

I know only basic spreadsheets not advanced

Comment: Voting to close because this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do get into the Datawarehousing field, it is fundamental for you to be "datamart" litterate.

First start here :

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mart

Then, dare taking a look there :

- http://www.information-management.com/infodirect/19991120/1675-1.html : it will give you an awesome step back and you'll be able to reply to questions like a pro, who has seen datamarts in real-life ecosystems.

And last, but not least, get as familiar as you can with the Map Reduce theory. Among others, take a jump here :

- http://www.informationweek.com/news/software/info_management/226600088

Keep us posted about your job interviews.